# $r = \sin(3\theta)$ Manual graph

Tags: polar-coordinates

What is the thought process behind the second line of the following, namely that the sin of 3 theta equals +/- 1?  Thank you.

$r = \sin(3\theta)$

$\sin3\theta = +- 1$

$3\theta = (2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$

...

Comment: It looks like this is being used to find the directions where the maximum and minimum values of $ \ r \ $ occur (keep in mind how "negative radius" is handled in working with polar curves).  What you have here is a three-petal rosette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it means $-1\leq3\theta\leq1$.

The other likelihood is that there's some other part we're not seeing which prevents $\sin(3\theta)$ taking the non-unitary values, thereby enabling the deduction that $\sin(3\theta)=-1$ or $\sin(3\theta)=1$.